Why is my selenium code failing when trying to check that there is a certain word inside of the URL?
I am using my terminal to run an automated test, and I want to check that the word is inside the URL. I am thinking maybe I have a syntax error as I am new to using selenium.
In VSCode this is what I have so far, and I was able to successfully get the chrome browser to open as well as have it input the site name, but I am unable to get it to scan the URL string. Could you help explain what is the issue?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest
import time

# Define the MyTestCase class
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def test_search_bar(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')

        # Wait for the search bar element to be interactable
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        search_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="text"]')))  # Use "text" instead of "textarea"

        search_bar.send_keys('Amazon.com' + Keys.ENTER)
        self.assertIn('Amazon.com', search_bar.get_attribute('value'))

        # Wait for the URL to update
        time.sleep(2)

        self.assertIn('Amazon', self.browser.current_url)  # Check for "Amazon" in the URL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)


the input's "value" attribute is not necessarily the same as your typing in the  box.  (input is evaluated when you submit the form...)  To evaluate you need the element.value.   You really don't need to assert this, anyway, just be sure to try catch the send_keys...  if no exception is thrown you know it was sent.  As is, this may throw Stale Element since you probably submit the value with the Enter key, then you are trying to use a method on it while the DOM may be updating.

There are a few issues...

Your search_bar locator is not correct. That locator doesn't find an element so it just times out. The locator should be
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea[name="q"]')


Your first assert will fail because you are entering "Amazon.com" and pressing ENTER and then you are asserting that the text is in the search bar but the page is already changed/changing because you hit ENTER. If you want to assert the text in the search bar, you need to separate the .send_keys() into two steps with the assert in the middle...
search_bar.send_keys('Amazon.com')
self.assertIn('Amazon.com', search_bar.get_attribute('value'))
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


Generally you don't want to use time.sleep(). Instead use another EC to wait for the URL to change
EC.url_changes(URL)



With all these changes, the code below has been tested and is working.
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Define the MyTestCase class
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def test_search_bar(self):
        URL = 'http://www.google.com'
        self.browser.get(URL)

        # Wait for the search bar element to be interactable
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        search_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea[name="q"]')))

        search_bar.send_keys('Amazon.com')
        self.assertIn('Amazon.com', search_bar.get_attribute('value'))
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # Wait for the URL to update
        wait.until(EC.url_changes(URL))

        self.assertIn('Amazon', self.browser.current_url)  # Check for "Amazon" in the URL

        self.browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)


I also was experimenting with setting the website to a variable. Not entirely sure when this would be useful, but it worked as well.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest
import time

# Define the MyTestCase class
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Set up the Chrome Browser
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()  
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def test_search_bar(self):
        URL = 'http://www.google.com'
        Site = 'https://www.amazon.com'
        self.browser.get(URL)

        # Wait for the search bar element to be interactable
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        search_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea[name="q"]')))  # Use "text" instead of "textarea"

        search_bar.send_keys('Amazon.com')
        self.assertIn('Amazon.com', search_bar.get_attribute('value'))
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # Wait for the URL to update
        wait.until(EC.url_changes(URL))

        self.assertIn('Amazon', self.browser.current_url)  # Check for "Amazon" in the URL

        # Navigate to Amazon.com
        self.browser.get(Site)

        # Get the browser type
        browser_type = self.browser.name

        # Print the browser type
        print("Browser Type:", browser_type)

        self.browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
